# Is it possible to efficiently write a string to a binary stream in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Straight to the point: Is it possible, in Python 3, to write a string to some binary stream without first holding a copy of it in memory (encode()), and without it being extremely slow.

By slow, I mean that if I have e.g. a 300m string, it takes hundreds of milliseconds to encode it to utf-8. In fact, it takes almost as long just to loop through and slice the string into 100k chunks. That's only slicing, no encoding `for ...: s[i:j]` which seems like i might be the memory allocation that's taking up most of the time, but I don't know how to verify that let-alone work around it.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/codecs.html#codecs.getwriter?

Comment: That comment should be an answer surely?

Comment: No, that does that equivalent of s.encode()

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @minitech, codecs are the way to go

Example of use:

```
fd = io.BytesIO()  # Ok here is a byte oriented stream
utfWriter = codecs.getWriter("utf8")
ufd = utfWriter(fd) # ufd is an encoding wrapper around fd
ufd.write("abcd éè efgh") #write a string with non ascii characters
print(fd.getvalue())

b'abcd \xc3\xa9\xc3\xa8 efgh'
```

That allows to do the encoding *on the flight*

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this does the equivalent of `.encode()`. It can be seen in the source code and I verified that it does in fact encode the whole string before writing anything with a dummy writer